# How to use jQuery UI in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to create an autocomplete text box using Jquery UI.
I can see that GetActiveItems works fine and i got a json result , but I can't see the autocomplete on the screen. I think that the problam is in the 'OnActionExecuted' when the ActionResult is being execute.
Please help me :)
thanks,
Siri

View:

```
<input type="text" id="mpvalue" name="mpvalue" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#mpvalue').autocomplete({
            source: '@Url.Action("GetActiveItems")'
        });
    })
</script>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult GetActiveItems(string term)
        {
            var result = from e in db.Items
                            where (e.IsBlock != true) && (e.Description.ToLower().Contains(term))
                            select e.Description;
            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: Please check the Browser log , Press F12 in chrome >> console tab, you will find if its a script error. , ensure the controller return is a proper Json which is matching to the expected format of AutoCompleate >> source property

Comment: Thanks. now i see it works but in a weird way. when there results i get this message at the bottom of the form "result is available, use up and down arrow keys to navigate" , i went it to be dropdwon or combox displayed. how can i do it? thanks